# $\int_{|z|=10} \dfrac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}\ dz = ? $

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello everybody:) I was solving this integral

> $$ \int_C \frac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}\ dz $$
>   for $C:|z|=10$

but I am not sure about my final result. I got the following results:
thank you in advance for your help

Singularities: $3\pi i/2$ and $-3\pi i/2$

I applied the residue theorem 
$$\frac{e^z}{(2z+3\pi i)(2z-3\pi i)}$$
for $z=3\pi i/2$
$$= \frac{e^{3\pi i/2}}{2z+3\pi i} = -\frac{1}{6\pi} $$

$z=-3πi/2$
$$= \frac{e^{-3\pi i/2}}{2z-3\pi i} = -\frac{1}{6\pi}$$

$$2\pi i\left(-\frac{1}{6\pi}-\frac{1}{6\pi}\right)=-\frac{2i}{3}$$

Comment: Try formatting your math with mathjax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sorry :)  I will do so :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_C \frac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}\rm dz $$

The function has singularities at $z=\pm\frac{3}{2}\pi i$, which are within the path of integration.

You can use Cauchy's Residue Theorem to evaluate this integral.

$$\int_C \frac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}\rm dz=2\pi i(Res_{z=\frac{3}{2}\pi i}+Res_{z=-\frac{3}{2}\pi i}) $$

$$Res_{z=\frac{3}{2}\pi i}=\lim_{z\to\frac{3}{2}\pi i}\frac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}(z-\frac{3}{2}\pi i)=\frac{\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{12\pi i}$$

Similarly for the other residue you get the complex conjugate due to the sine being an odd function.

Thus $$\int_C \frac{e^z}{4z^2+9\pi^2}\rm dz=2\pi i(\frac{\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{12\pi i}+\frac{\frac{-i\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{12\pi i})=\frac{1}{6} $$